# Get the value of select

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Here's my code. I want to get the value of selected option and use the value in another sql query.

For example:
`SELECT * FROM section WHERE GradeLevel = '$GradeLevel' AND SectionName = '$GradeSection`

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sample";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$GradeLevel = $_GET['glevel'];
$StudentID = $_GET['studentID'];

$BirthCertificate = $_POST['BirthCertificate'];  
$GoodMoral = $_POST['GoodMoral'];
$ReportCard = $_POST['ReportCard'];

echo 'Grade Level :  '.$GradeLevel.' <br/>'; 
//Section


$sql = "SELECT * FROM section WHERE GradeLevel='$GradeLevel'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>

    Section Name: 
    <select name="GradeSection" id="GradeSection" style="width:30%;"> 

    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Section = $row["SectionName"]; 

        echo '
            <option value="'.$Section.'"> '.$Section.'  </option> ';
    }

    echo "</select>";
} 

$GradeSection = $_POST['GradeSection'];
?>
```

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really **use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: So, what is your actual question? You shown us an example query. Have you tried it to do it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is the error or problem ?

Comment: the $GradeSection returns empty value thats the error

Comment: @EuniseP, the words you choose and the content you include in the question here is important. If `$_POST['GradeSection']` is empty, that's unrelated to any database calls you're making. As it stands, the question is unclear because you can't point out a specific error or problem.

Comment: i need the value of selected option....and the selected value will be use to query for example the value of $GradeSection = honesty then the mysql query will be SELECT * FROM section WHERE GradeLevel = '$GradeLevel' AND SectionName = 'honesty'

Answer (score 0):

Try This
Put it above $GradeSection = $_POST['GradeSection'];

```
if ($GradeSection != "" || $GradeSection != NULL)
{
$sql += "AND SectionName = '$GradeSection'";
}
```